# On scroll trigger click event on pagination next

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I have a listing page with pagination at the bottom. I'm trying to turn this into an infinite loading page.

The click event works when you've scrolled to the bottom, but for some reason in the network tab its calling ?page=2, ?page=3,?page=4,?page=5 and loading all the products from those pages, and then displaying page 2 products :/

Here is my JS for the scroll

```
            $(window).scroll(function () { //bind scroll event
                console.log('we scrolling out here babyyyy');
                var intBottomMargin = 300; //Pixels from bottom when script should trigger

                //if less than intBottomMargin px from bottom
                if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) {
                    $(".js-next-page").trigger('click'); //trigger click
                }
            });
```

Here is the HTML for the pagination

```
    <ul class="listing-navigation__view">
        @if (Model.Pages != null && Model.Pages.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var p in Model.Pages)
            {
                if (p.Title == "Cancel View All" && Athena.Core.Tools.Misc.GetQueryStringAsInt("feature") == 1)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (p.Title == "Previous")
                {
                    rel = "rel=\"prev\"";
                }
                if (p.Title == "Next")
                {
                    rel = "rel=\"next\"";
                }
                <li class="page-@p.Title.ToLower().Replace(" ", "-") @(p.CurrentPage ? "current" : "")"><a href="@p.PageUrl" class="paging js-next-page" @Html.Raw(rel)>@p.Title</a></li>
            }
        }       
    </ul>
```

Any help or advice on how to approach this would be great!

Thanks,

Comment: What about this behaviour is unexcpected ? Isn't that exactly what a click on your next button should do ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are generating links for all pages, and they all have the classname `js-next-page` so your script will click ALL of the links at the same time.

Try to find a way to trigger the click only for the link you are interested in, possibly with something like this:

```
$("li.current+li .js-next-page").trigger('click');
```